# Orbiting an object around another object, but it doesn't move

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I'm trying to make a visual "simulation" of the solar system using OpenGL and am using this function to orbit a planet around the sun (in a circular orbit).

```
glm::vec3 application::orbit(glm::vec3 thisPlanet, glm::vec3 otherPlanet, float rotSpeed, const time &dt)
{
    float radius = glm::distance(thisPlanet, otherPlanet);
    float angle = acosf((thisPlanet.x - otherPlanet.x) / radius) - atanf(1.0f) * 4.0f;
    angle += dt.as_seconds() * rotSpeed;

    if (angle > 2 * atanf(1.0f) * 4.0f)
        angle -= 2 * atanf(1.0f) * 4.0f;
    
    float x = otherPlanet.x + cosf(angle) * radius;
    float z = otherPlanet.z + sinf(angle) * radius;

    return glm::vec3(x, thisPlanet.y, z);
}
```

The function is called every frame like this:

```
void application::tick(const time &dt)
{
   if (m_keyboard.key_released(GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE)) {
      m_running = false;
   }

   m_controller.update(m_keyboard, m_mouse, dt);

   m_cube_rotation += dt.as_seconds();

   m_mercury_position = orbit(m_mercury_position, m_sun_position, 2.0f, dt);

  // glm::mat4 world = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), m_cube_position)
  //    * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), m_cube_rotation, glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f)));

   glm::mat4 sun = glm::translate(glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f)), m_sun_position)
       * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), m_cube_rotation, glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f)));

   glm::mat4 mercury = glm::translate(glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)), m_mercury_position)
       * glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f), m_cube_rotation, glm::normalize(glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f)));

   //m_crate.set_transform(world);
   m_sun.set_transform(sun);
   m_mercury.set_transform(mercury);

   const int frames_per_second = int(1.0f / dt.as_seconds());
   const int frame_timing_ms = int(dt.as_milliseconds());

   m_overlay.pre_frame(m_width, m_height);
   m_overlay.push_line("FPS: %d (%dms)", frames_per_second, frame_timing_ms);
}
```

Why doesn't the planet move?

Comment: Hi Anton, it looks like you're trying to simulate orbit by moving the planet around in a circle? Most orbits are actually elliptical. Take a look at my code: https://github.com/sjhalayka/mercury_orbit_glut/blob/54dd9f93b6f8a7c4dd808d8cc42e93f3055d8ec6/main.cpp#L38 -- it is a Mercury orbit simulator in OpenGL / GLUT. And when integrating the orbit, it is HIGHLY recommended that you use RK4 (e.g. Runge-Kutta order 4). The Euler integration does not model the orbit very well. There are also symplectic integration schemes (e.g. Verlet).

Comment: Its not an actual simulation of a orbit, im trying to move it in a circle

Comment: Have you checked which value for `angle` is calculated each time `application::orbit` is called? I have the suspicion that it is the same angle each time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I would construct the model matrix:

```
mat4 model_mat;
const vec3 n_forward = dir.x;
const vec3 n_up = vec3(0, 1, 0);
const vec3 n_left = dir.z;

// construct a basis and a translation
model_mat[0] = normalize(vec4(n_left, 0.0f));
model_mat[1] = normalize(vec4(n_forward, 0.0f));
model_mat[2] = normalize(vec4(n_up, 0.0f));
model_mat[3] = vec4(p, 1.0f);
```

The position (e.g. p) is given by the parametric circle equation p = r cos(t) + r sin(t), where t is the elapsed time and r is the circular orbit radius. Also see: https://www.mathopenref.com/coordparamcircle.html

Does this help at all?

Comment: And how does it solve the problem that the planet doesn't move?